# Given a list with several junk links, how to extract all the links that finish in .pdf in this way?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, urlparse

I have a pandas dataframe column with several links on each cell:

```
Name|COL
San Diego|'https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2004/019787_S30_gasTOC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787s022_gas.pdf https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787s021_gas.pdf https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787-s017_report.pdf https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/293-_9302SDFS 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787-s018_gas.pdf https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787-s017_report.pdf https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/98/019787-S16_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/97/019787-S15_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/97/019787-S14_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/97/19787-S013_gas.pdf https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/96/019787-S12_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/96/019787-S11_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/96/019787-S10_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/pre96/019787-S9_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/pre96/019787-S8_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/96/19-787s007_Amlodipine.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/pre96/019787-S6_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/pre96/019787-S5_gas 2.5 KM, 5.0 KM, & 10.0 KM GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/pre96/019787-S4_gas GAS_TPC.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/pre96/019787-S3_gas_toc.cfm https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/pre96/019787-S2_gas GAS_TPC.cfm'
Washington|'https://foo.com/energy_docs/a32/2007/022136.cfm'
Texas|'https://foo.com/energy/29380/no_ant/USA/2/2007.pdf'
```

How can I extract all the links that end in `.pdf` in the following way:

```
Name|COL
San Diego|https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787s022_gas.pdf
San Diego|https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787s021_gas.pdf
San Diego|https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787-s017_report.pdf
San Diego|https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787-s018_gas.pdf 
San Diego|https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787-s017_report.pdf 
San Diego|https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/97/19787-S013_gas.pdf
Washington|NaN
Texas|https://foo.com/energy/29380/no_ant/USA/2/2007.pdf
```

I tried to:

​

```
import re

def url_extractor(row):

    url=str(row)

    r = re.compile('(http[^\s]+\.pdf)')

    urls = r.findall(url)

    if len(urls) == 0:

        return 'NaN'

    else:

        return ' '.join(urls)

​
```

In:

```
df4['COL'] = df4['COL'].apply(url_extractor)
df4
```

Out:

```
    Name    COL
0   San Diego   https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787s022_g...
1   Washington  NaN
2   Texas   https://foo.com/energy/29380/no_ant/USA/2/2007...
```

However I do not understand how to do the stacking/splitting row part in order to get one link/url on each row. For example, let's check the first row:

In:

```
df4['COL'][0]
```

Out:

> 'https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787s022_gas.pdf
>   https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787s021_gas.pdf
>   https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787-s017_report.pdf
>   https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787-s018_gas.pdf
>   https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787-s017_report.pdf
>   https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/97/19787-S013_gas.pdf'

Each link should be "mapped" to its name which is `San Diego`.

Comment: Is that your actual data? If so why would `(?<=href=").*?(?=")` be the regex you tried. It's *miles away* from working.

Comment: Ups sorry... I am trying several things... I updated... @Vallentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is already loaded into a pandas dataframe, you can use the pandas built-in string methods to break the strings in `COL` into lists, extract the elements you want from the lists, restructure the col of lists into a long Series, and then merge that with the original data frame

```
# break COL into lists of strings that only end if '.pdf'
COL_series = df.COL.str.split().apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y.endswith('pdf')])
# create a long format series from the lists
COL_series = COL_series.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
COL_series.name = 'COL'

# merge with df
pd.merge(df.Name.reset_index(), 
         COL_series.reset_index(), 
         how='outer', 
         on='index').drop('index', axis=1)

# returns:
        Name                                                         COL
0  San Diego        https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787s022_gas.pdf
1  San Diego      https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787s021_gas.pdf
2  San Diego  https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787-s017_report.pdf
3  San Diego       https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/99/19787-s018_gas.pdf
4  San Diego  https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/2000/19787-s017_report.pdf
5  San Diego       https://foo.com/energy_docs/tyv/97/19787-S013_gas.pdf
6 Washington                                                         NaN
7      Texas          https://foo.com/energy/29380/no_ant/USA/2/2007.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nonetheless, my dataframe has other columns (3 more columns), when I applied this it removed the other columns... How to do this without removing the other 3 columns?... I just put two columns in the question for space/visualization issues.. I tried to remove the Name in pd.merge(), but it added a COL_x and COL_y

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `[^<]` you should do `[^\s]` or shorter `\S`. Then after that add `\.pdf`.

```
(http\S+\.pdf)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/JNbaZd/1)

**Edit:**

Yes you can also use word boundaries if you want to.

```
(\bhttp.*?\.pdf\b)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/JNbaZd/2)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I could do this with `\b`... Any idea of how to do the splitting/stacking rows to just leave one link in each row?...

Comment: Yes you can also use `\b` (updated and added example to the answer). Splitting how? If there's multiple then how would you decide which one to keep?